# Creating User In Docker Container

Tags: docker

I am using a publicly hosted docker project, but the documentation on running it with docker-compose is nonexistent.

Here is the docker run command:

```
docker run -d -v /persist/gravsite:/apps/var garywiz/docker-grav \
     --create-user anyuser:/apps/var
```

What I need to know is the equivalent for the `--create-user` in the `docker-compose.yml` file.

Here is my current entry:

```
grav:
    image: garywiz/docker-grav
    container_name: grav
    restart: always
    user: gravuser
    environment:
        - VIRTUAL_HOST=www.domain.com,domain.com
        - VIRTUAL_PORT=8080
    volumes:
        - /home/gravuser:/apps/var
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: What is create user? Some argument passed to the `docker-grav` image?

Comment: I think so. I tried adding `command: ["create-user","gravuser"]` to the definition with no luck.

Comment: You'd need to use the same format. `command: ["--create-user", "anyuser:/apps/var"]`

Comment: Unfortunately, that still didn't work. Gave me the error: `ERROR: for grav  Cannot start service grav: linux spec user: unable to find user gravuser: no matching entries in passwd file`. It works fine as a docker-run command though.

Comment: There are inconsistencies between your run and compose file, the volume for instance. As far as the command goes, that's equivalent, so there's something off about your environment. Can you share the entire compose file that's not working (as is) and the full `docker run` command that is working (as is).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to translate the execution of the command in docker-compose, it would look like this:

this command:

```
docker run -d -v /persist/gravsite:/apps/var garywiz/docker-grav \
     --create-user anyuser:/apps/var
```

is equivalent to:

```
grav:
    image: garywiz/docker-grav
    volumes:
        - /persist/gravsite:/apps/var
    command: --create-user anyuser:/apps/var
```